# Recursion methods

Tags: java, recursion

I have a question.
If the task is to write down a recursive method,is it ok to create another recursive method that will be called in the original method,would it be considered as a recursive method?

Comment: I think this is not a good question for the stackoverflows' criteria.  please read again this [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As @Pavel Smirnov says a recursive method is a method that call him self

Comment: in some cases to start the recursion one need to setup some vars...in this case it is okay to do that, the method which is call inside is the actual recursion

Answer (score 3):

yes , Recursive method call itself in body

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's fine, and in fact it is a common pattern. Sometimes you need to do some initial setup before you can begin recursing and therefore need a public method which does the setup and a helper method which does the actual recursion.

For example, to display a tree with levels of indentation:

**Setup**

```
public void printTree(Node tree) {
    // Setup: Start with 0 indentation.
    printNode(tree, 0);
}
```

**Helper**

```
private void printNode(Node node, int spaces) {
    // Print the current node.
    for (int i = 0; i < spaces; ++i) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.printf("- %s%n", node.getValue());

    // Recursive calls: print the children indented 4 extra spaces.
    for (Node child: node.getChildren()) {
        printNode(node, spaces + 4);
    }
}
```

Comment: So for example:I have to write a recursive method for marsenne numbers, marsenne number is 2^i -1 for every positive i it would be ok to create recursive method called power n^m and this method would be called in the orighinal method,am I right?